# Bitcoind daemon return "timeoffset" : -10,-15,-50,-60 and more

Tags: bitcoind

Bitcoind daemon return "timeoffset" : -10,-15,-50,-60 and more..

Timeoffset value is constantly increasing(decreases*) (~ "-1" per day), i dont can restart daemon with command -reindex / -rescan (daemon restart with reindex/rescan is very long).

**How i can fix it ?**

Blocks count is valid (Sometimes there with delays 1-4 blocks)

```
{
    "version" : 110200,
    "protocolversion" : 70002,
    "walletversion" : 60000,
    "balance" : 305.11300817,
    "blocks" : 406061,
    "timeoffset" : -75,
    "connections" : 10,
    "proxy" : "",
    "difficulty" : 166851513282.77719116,
    "testnet" : false,
    "keypoololdest" : 1457952689,
    "keypoolsize" : 10001,
    "paytxfee" : 0.00000000,
    "relayfee" : 0.00005000,
    "errors" : ""
}
```

Wallet.dat is big **~95mb**, with "connections" : 35 - problem same..

Server(XEN) - 4gb ram / Xeon-2.60Ghz*4 / HDD 130gb/ Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS / 100mbit/s

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The timeoffset simply shows the relative time with respect to the peers you are connected to (actually the median of your peers). A consistent increase in the count would indicate that your server's clock is [drifting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clock_drift), hence your server is counting time a bit faster than it's peers. This is normal (although 1 second/day drift is already quite a lot) and is not a cause for concern. If you'd like to fix it I suggest to synchronize with some timeserver over [NTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_Time_Protocol).

Comment: thanks, u fully right, after synchronize time and restart daemon, timeoffset fixed..

Comment: Glad I could help :-)